# Leaflet with two switchable maps

Tags: maps, leaflet, layer

I have two types of map tiles, and I want to be able to switch between them using layers with a custom html control. Both will have the same tilesize and the other options that I have set. The only difference is that one is located in normal map folder and the other in gridmap folder.

This is the code that I use to display one map:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
                maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
                minZoom: mapMinZoom,
                zoomControl: false,
                crs: L.CRS.MySimple
            }).setView([0, 0], 2);

            L.tileLayer('normalmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
                minZoom: mapMinZoom,
                maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
                tileSize: 268,
                noWrap: true,
                tms: false,
                continuousWorld: true
            }).addTo(map);
```

I tried to follow the leaflet example: http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html
But no luck.

Can someone explain to me how to add 2 maps with a custom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to both your tile layers and add/remove them as appropiate:

```
var map = L.map(...);

var tilelayer1 = L.tileLayer('map1/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', { ... });
var tilelayer2 = L.tileLayer('map2/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', { ... });

tilelayer1.addTo(map);

document.getElementById('switch-layers').addEventHandler('click', function(ev){
    if (map.hasLayer(tilelayer1)) {
        map.addLayer(tilelayer2);
        map.removeLayer(tilelayer1);
    } else {
        map.addLayer(tilelayer1);
        map.removeLayer(tilelayer2);
    }
})
```

Keep in mind that you can create layers and not add them to the map right away.